# How to kill the Hunter Demon in DmC: Devil May Cry on the first level?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

I'm struggling on the first boss in Devil May Cry. Everytime he jumps on the Roller Coast he kills me. How do you avoid his grapple attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to avoid his gun attack as it turns into a grapple. If he does get you, you're able to escape but it's instant kill if you don't. I've followed the guide linked below and it worked for me. I struggled for a bit too

http://www.gamersheroes.com/dmc-devil-may-cry-hunter-boss-guide

Answer (score 0):

I never got caught once so I cannot comment on how to escape. But to avoid his grapple attack you just need to use a well timed dodge - hold the left stick in either direction and press the dodge button `R1`/`RB`.

To drain his life during the end of level fight you just need to smash his face in! Once he jumps up out of reach you will be instructed to shoot him in the head. Do exactly this, face him and open fire. Dodge any attacks you need to, but it shouldn't take much to get him back on the ground where you can start smashing his face in again :D

Comment: I can attest to the above.
I never got caught either. Just press the buttons (provided you play with a controller) to evade. As soon as his "shot" hits the ground, dodge. As I said I never got caught doing it that way.